# Accessing an annotation's value inside the method to which it is applied to

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Question: Is there a way to access an annotation's value inside the method to which it is being applied to?

Example: Say I have an annotation like so:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    int value default 0;
}
```

Next, I have a class C with functions f1/f2 that use this annotation. The value is known up-front during compile time.

```
public class C {

    @MyAnnotation(value = 1)
    public void f1() {
         // Is there a way to get the 'value=1' here??
         g();
    }

    @MyAnnotation(value = -1)
    public void f2() {
         g();
    }
}
```

And I have another function g that must print 'positive' or 'negative' or 'zero' based on the annotation's value.

```
public static void g() {
    // Must print 'positive' or 'negative' or 'zero'
}
```

1) Is there a way for f1/f2 to 'capture' the annotation's value and pass it along to g() as a parameter?

2) My current solution to this problem is to do this:

- Have an initialization step in g()'s class to iterate through all of C's functions and pre-construct a hashmap of function name to value (Eg: {'C.f1': 1, 'C.f2': -1}). To do this, I use getClass(), getMethods() and getAnnotations() and filter to have only use MyAnnotation's.
- Change g()'s signature to accept class and method name and use that as a key to look in the hashmap. The new call in f1 will be g(this, "f1") <-- I explicitly write "f1" to avoid looking in the stack trace for the method name.

Needless to say, this is very ugly and I'm hoping there's a simpler way to do this. Thanks.

Edit: I am not using (and don't plan to) the Spring Framework for this project.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a good design choice to access the annotation information inside the annotated method. [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html) represents meta-information which is not a part of the program. Usually they are accessible by a program runner that creates objects and run methods via reflection.

If you want to pass an attribute or a property to a method you can simply define a parameter which can be set by your "runner" depending on the annotation value.

However, you can find out which class and method you are in using the `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` method and then access the annotation information.

Here is an example showing both approaches. It shows how to locate the current method in the stack trace and how to run the program via reflection and pass the method parameter.

```
public class StackTrace {

    @Target({ElementType.METHOD})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public static  @interface MyAnnotation {
        int value() default 0;
    }

    public static class C {

        @MyAnnotation(value = 1)
        public void f1() { g(); }

        @MyAnnotation(value = -1)
        public void f2() {
            g();
        }
    }

    public static class X {
        @MyAnnotation(value = 1)
        public static void x1(int param) { System.out.println("Param1: " + param);}

        @MyAnnotation(value = -1)
        public static void x2(int param) { System.out.println("Param2: " + param); }
    }


    private static void g() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement traceElement = stackTraceElements[3];
        try {
            Class<?> type = Class.forName(traceElement.getClassName());
            String methodName = traceElement.getMethodName();
            Method method = type.getMethod(methodName);
            System.out.println(methodName + ": " +
                    method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class).value());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void boo() throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        for (Method m : X.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            MyAnnotation annotation = m.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
            if (annotation != null) {
                m.invoke(null, annotation.value());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        C c = new C();
        c.f1();
        c.f2();

        boo();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
f1: 1
f2: -1
Param1: 1
Param2: -1
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why it isn't a good design choice to access the annotation information inside the annotated method? I want to use the annotation to set (or enforce) certain properties/attributes on a method. Why would it be wrong to access that property information "in-place"? Perhaps I'm not correctly understanding the purpose of annotations.


Yes, the stack trace method will work but as I indicated in my question, I'm trying to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @user2602740 I tried to clarify my answer a little bit. It'd be great if you can provide some background information on why do you need to assess the annotation value inside the method.

Comment: `If you want to pass an attribute or a property to a method you can simply define a parameter which can be set by your "runner" depending on the annotation value`   <-- Can you please show me an example for this? Also, my actual use case is pretty complex but here's a simple illustration of it. In [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html) there's an example with an @Author annotation. If I had different @Authors for my f1/f2 functions, I would like my g() function to be able to print those different names.

Comment: @user2602740 I have updated my answer with the example.